# Windows 7 OCR API

Tags: c#, windows-7, sdk, ocr, modi

I have been reviewing replacements for the Office 2007 MODI OCR (OneNote's 2010 solution has lesser quality/results than 2007 :-( ). I notice that Windows 7 contains an OCR library once you install the [optional tiff filter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd755985%28WS.10%29.aspx)

The OCR component gets installed to

```
%programfiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\OCR\7.0\xocr3.psp.dll
```

but I don't see any API for it?

Does anyone see how this can be interfaced preferably in C#?

ANSWER: Found the soluation, once the optional tiff ifilter win7 feature is installed, i can then get a textoutput of a screenshot using the code/exe on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx. Also if add the same [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.tiff\PersistentHandler] for .png and .jpg then OCR also works for jpg and png's.

Comment: The main API seems defined in thocrapi.dll. But good luck with programming against an undocument, possibly changing target. You'd better spend some money and get a commercial library instead of wasting your time here.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Tessnet](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) OCR is a good solution, but pretty old (last release from 2009). There are couple of very good free OCR solutions available for .NET:
2. [Asprise C# OCR SDK](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/download.php?lang=csharp). Very good and fast one.
3. [Microsoft Research Project Hawaii](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/students/default.aspx) <strike>Web-based (cloud) OCR solution with full docs and samples</strike> (discontinued 2013)
4. [Bing OCR](http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/ocr) <strike>Web based (cloud) OCR replacement for above.</strike> (discontinued March 2014)

Comment: taught me something, I only knew about tessnet (on my budget, at least ;-). Forewarning: It doesn't look like you can distribute software with the 'free' Aprise OCR - so 'free' probably belongs in quotes: http://asprise.com/product/ocr/faq.php?lang=vb

Comment: Havent' read their license fully, as used that in non-commercial, personal project a while ago. Have to recheck it. There was also a third library I used the most. It was the nicest one, but forgot it's name. Will post you with info on that if I manage to find it somewhere:)

Comment: Piotr, thank you for mentioning Asprise [C# OCR Component Library](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/c%23-sharp.net-ocr-api-overview.html). Our dev team has spent a lot effort to improve the accuracy and speed of the OCR. Let us know if you have any suggestion to make it even better :)

Comment: At $5k for the cheapest version, Asprise appears to be anything but free: http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/c%23-sharp.net-ocr-source-code-open-order.html

Comment: @Jimmy Well, there was one at the time of writing (there is a free trial now though). And OP didn't specifically ask for free libraries so I included it.

Answer (score 2):

Try TessNet, using the suggestions I made to the Poster in this post (enlarge image, use separate process):
[c# OCR can't recognize digits (tesseract 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475256)

Answer (score 1):

I was exploring the windows 7 dlls and I found 3 libraries that might be useful: thocr.psp.dll ,xocr3.psp.dll, and ximage3b.dll. In [this website](http://www.fileinspect.com/fileinfo/ximage3b-dll/) and other similar websites I found out that ximage3b is a Windows system ocr engine. I have been looking for documentation online but I have not been succesful, but hey! at least I know that it's there, I will give you guys an update if I find out how to use it with C#/C/C++.